# php curl post request and get result response

Tags: php, curl

is it possible to get result (see below image) using curl for this site example: http://poslaju.com.my/track-trace/#trackingIds=EP024922993MY

here is my code so far, not working:

```
/*$params = array(
"trackingIds" => "EP024922993MY"
);*/

$url = rawurlencode("http://poslaju.com.my/track-trace/#trackingIds=EP024922993MY");

$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$reponse = curl_getinfo($ch);

curl_close($ch);

var_dump($result);
var_dump($reponse);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very first: I'm using `Firebug` add-on and see what happen

[image]
Here one ajax get content from other site

We have this link

```
https://apis.pos.com.my/apigateway/as2corporate/api/v2trackntracewebapijson/v1/?id=EP024922993MY&Culture=En
```

In request of header we can see require `X-User-Key`

[image]

Now we must find X-User-Key => We can view source

[image]

Now we build source code

```
<?php
function _curl($url,$post="",$usecookie = false,$_sock = false,$timeout = false,$x_user_key = false) {  
    $ch = curl_init();
    if($post) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST ,1);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    }
    if($timeout){
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
    }
    if($_sock){
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $_sock);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/528.18 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile/7A341 Safari/528.16");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'X-Apple-Tz: 0',
    'X-Apple-Store-Front: 143444,12'
    ));
    if($x_user_key){
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'X-User-Key: '.$x_user_key,
        'Referer: http://poslaju.com.my/track-trace/',
        'Origin: http://poslaju.com.my'
        ));
    }
    if ($usecookie) { 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $usecookie); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $usecookie);    
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); 
    $result=curl_exec ($ch); 
    curl_close ($ch); 
    return $result; 
}
function getStr($string,$start,$end){
    $str = explode($start,$string,2);
    $str = explode($end,$str[1],2);
    return $str[0];
}
$url = 'http://poslaju.com.my/track-trace/';
$result_curl = _curl($url,'','','','','');
$x_user_key = getStr($result_curl,'{ "X-User-Key": "','" }');

$id_track = 'EP024922993MY';
$url = 'https://apis.pos.com.my/apigateway/as2corporate/api/v2trackntracewebapijson/v1/?id='.$id_track.'&Culture=En';
$result_curl = _curl($url,'','','','',$x_user_key);
echo $result_curl;
?>
```

Change `id` on your mind

You can get `json` content

Use `print_r(json_decode($content_you_got)`

And result you will have like this

[image]

Comment: You should explain how you found that endpoint so that the person asking the question learns how to find it themselves in the future.

Comment: I'm updating my answer.

Comment: sorry, still didn't get it. return null result

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'm updating how to get X-User-Key for authenticate with this site xD

Comment: result: string(21) "Bad secret key found."

Comment: @user3613026 Are you try this?

Comment: still trying, sorry newbie here

Comment: xD No problems bro

Comment: Where is the line i'm missing. You can vote accepted answer by click tick icon xD